# Change page title with history.js

Tags: javascript, pushstate, history.js

with history.js we can change the page title with

```
History.pushState(data,title,url);
```

but imagine my scenario, I'm using `window.onstatechange` to fire an ajax call and **then** retrieve the page title from collected data. 
I surely don't want to fire `onstatechange` twice, one to push the **url** and one to change the **title**. 
Sure I can use an old `document.title` but I wonder if there's a different (clever? better?) way to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to change the page title immediately? Before the ajax response?

Comment: after the ajax response, because the page title is in the response too.

Comment: What cleverer or better way of document.title would you expect? I think document.title is perfect for this.